# macOS Aqua LookAndFeel JRadioButtonMenuItem like JCheckBoxMenuItem

Tags: java, java-8, macos-sierra, look-and-feel

```
PopupMenu.add(new javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem("JCheckBoxMenuItem", true));
PopupMenu.add(new javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem("JCheckBoxMenuItem", false));
PopupMenu.addSeparator();
PopupMenu.add(new javax.swing.JRadioButtonMenuItem("JRadioButtonMenuItem", true));
PopupMenu.add(new javax.swing.JRadioButtonMenuItem("JRadioButtonMenuItem", false));
```

**Aqua**

[image]

Using `JPopupMenu` with LookAndFeel `Aqua` `"com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel"`...
As you can see the `JRadioButtonMenuItem` is presented like `JCheckBoxMenuItem`.

Comparing with other LookAndFeels.

**GTK**

[image]

**Windows**

[image]

**Windows Classic**

[image]

**Motif**

[image]

**Metal**

[image]

Is it normal or is it a bug?